# How to show http response code in Prometheus alert while using Prometheus, backbox exporter and alert manager

Tags: prometheus

I want to get the HTTP response code when the alert is triggered on failure.
How to include http status code in description for my current configuration?

```
- alert: EndpointDown
        expr: probe_success{job=~"healthchecks"} == 0
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: "critical"
        annotations:
          summary: "{{ $labels.service }} is down"
          description: "{{ $labels.service }} is down. Please check ASAP. \n\n **Repository**: {{ $labels.portal }} \n **Service**: {{ $labels.service }} \n **URL**: {{ $labels.instance }} \n **Status**: Down with Satus Code {{http_status_code_value}}"
```

I tried adding below line in description, but didn't worked out.  Prometheus itself is throwing error

Tried:

```
Status Code {{http_status_code_value}}
```

Error:

> err="error loading config from "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml": one or more errors occurred while applying the new configuration (--config.file="/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml")"